# Jquery image slider with pagination

Tags: jquery, css

I am novice in jQuery. I'd like to make a slideshow just like [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/)

But I have made something like [here](http://kaidul.web44.net/slider/)

The code is [here](http://www.kaidul.web44.net/slider/code.php)

Please help me to make a pagination like ebay.com

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of jquree sliders, you can easily find a pagination example from some search. here are some of the free easily silders..
http://www.noupe.com/jquery/cool-and-useful-jquery-image-and-content-sliders-and-slideshows.html or also here   some pagination http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/ Gud luck...!

Answer (score 2):

You're not the first one who is doing a slideshow.
Instead of reinventing the wheel, may I suggest you to use [Nivo](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use premade jQuery Plugins like http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ that do exactly that and more.